How to give a unique ID to new item in NGRX reducer?
I have a simple todo list that seems to work fine but I'm not sure I'm implementing the part where I'm adding a new item with a unique ID using Math.random() to the todo list properly.  I want to give it a unique ID basically and then when deleting it, find that value, is the way I'm doing it fine?
export interface TodoState {
  todos: Todo[];
}

export const initialState: TodoState = {
  todos: [
    {
      id: 1,
      task: '1',
      description: 'description 1',
      completed: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      task: '2',
      description: 'description 2',
      completed: false,
    },
  ],

};

export const todoReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(TodoActions.addTodo, (state, { text }) => ({
    ...state,
    todos: [
      ...state.todos,
      {
        id: Math.random(), // id: state.todos.length + 1
        task: '' + Math.random() + '',
        description: text,
        completed: false,
      },
    ],
  })),
  on(TodoActions.resetTodo, () => initialState)
);

Stackblitz: Link

there could be multiple way to implement it.

As you have use Math.Rando() function
Take Id MAX(ID)+1 When ADD
Take Unique Time Span


When you work with NgRx/store I highly recommend to use Chrome DevTools: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/. In that way you can see the actual values and determine if your logic is working as you've intended
